# access formData on server as empty POST

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "server.php,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: formData,
    cache: true,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {  alert(data);    }
});
```

and in the server.php

```
  print_r($_REQUEST['object']);
```

but i get only Array() empty

Comment: How are you generating `formData`? What browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: Can you show us the `formData` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem of using older jquery version file and by replacing with the latest do the job. here is the old jquery

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
```

and the new jquery file is as:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

i have no idea of the changes in both files but when i try the latest version it allow me to upload the file and now i prove that the latest versions are better to use and try to use the latest version;

same answer as on [FormData cannot appended with File Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254564/formdata-cannot-appended-with-file-object)